# How to measure Elevation using GPS technology for iPhone SDK?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, gps

There are few apps like Strava which records users movements using GPS. It also measures the elevation of the road on which they travelled.

I would like to know how can we measure elevation of the road using iPhone SDK?

Please let me know.

Comment: Two ways... either it references a table full of elevation data given lat/long or it uses the altitude given by the location data (but this will be inaccurate on the ground)

Comment: can you please be more specific as to from where they would be getting Elevation data, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [Google Elevation API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/elevation/)

Example [here](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/elevation/json?locations=39.7391536,-104.9847034&sensor=true)

Then use a JSON parser to retrieve the values

Answer (score 0):

CoreLocation is what you want to use (although it is generally quite inaccurate I've found) 
first import the core location framework in the .h:

```
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>
```

followed by in the .m:

```
- (void)locationUpdate:(CLLocation *)location {

altitudeLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Altitude - %f", [location altitude]];
}
```

This is given in height from sea level